# Dynamic if statement using string variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an object in JavaScript that starts by looking like this:

```
variable = {1: 'No', 2: 'No', 3: 'No'}
```

and it dynamically changes based on user and updates to look like this, for example:

```
variabel = {1: 'Yes', 2: 'No', 3: 'Yes'}
```

I now want to dynamically build an if statement for any keys that have a yes to be like this:

```
if (feature.properties.1.indexOf(variable.1)!=-1 && feature.properties.3.indexOf(variable.3)!=-1)
```

Is there a way to do this?  I tried looping over the object to dynamically build a string statement and then attempted to unstring it to be used in the if statement but had no luck.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you can't have `x.1` but have to use `x[1]` instead

Comment: What is in feature.properties... And why are you using strings for booleans?

Comment: feature.properties is coming from a json object.  And I am not sure about the boolean vs string, does it matter?

Comment: So are you trying to test if, for every own property of *feature.properties*, there is a same–named property of *variable* whose value is a substring of the *feature.properties* value?

Answer (score 2):

```
var success = true;

for (var i in variable) {
   if (feature.properties[i].indexOf(variable[i]) === -1) {
       success = false;
       break;
   }
}

// evaluate success here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the properties present in your desired comparison target (called "reference" for simplicity) and check the corresponding properties in the feature. If a property exists in the reference but not the feature, this will consider the validation a failure.

```js
var reference = {
  1: 'Yes',
  2: 'No',
  3: 'Yes'
};

var feature1 = {
  properties: {
    1: 'Yes',
    3: null
  }
};

var feature2 = {
  properties: {
    1: 'Yes',
    3: 'Yes'
  }
};

function compareReference(ref, feature) {
  var props = feature.properties;
  return Object.keys(ref).reduce(function(prev, key) {
    console.log('comparing', key, ref[key], props[key], prev);
    if (ref[key] === 'Yes') {
      // Only compare yes values
      return prev && props[key] === 'Yes'; 
    } else {
      return prev;
    }
  }, true);
}

document.getElementById('r1').textContent = '' + compareReference(reference, feature1);
document.getElementById('r2').textContent = '' + compareReference(reference, feature2);
```

```html
<div id="r1"></div>
<div id="r2"></div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second object return true? *every* might be a better choice than *reduce*.

Comment: I was originally trying to build a string statement to just insert into the if statement (unstringed) but can't figure out how to make the string not a string.

Comment: @EvanL If you already have an object representing the desired options and an object with the actual options, you can replace the `if` condition with a function call. Building and evaluating a string at runtime is poor practice, since it's very difficult to debug and can cause other problems.

Comment: Okay, I will try that.  Thanks.  (I am a bit new to using javascript if that is not obvious)